# How to escape special regex characters in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I use `re.findall(p, text)` to match a pattern generally, but now I came across a question:

I just want `p` to be matched as a normal string, not regex.

For example: p may contain '+' or '*', I don't want these characters have special meanings as in regex. In another word, I want p to be matched character by character.

In this case `p` is unknown to me, so I can't add '\' into it to ignore special character.

Comment: If you don't know `p`, how can you use it as a regex?

Comment: @Marcin: He has no a priori information about `p`, so he can't hardcode the already escaped string. Don't see why this was downvoted?

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, maybe, but why couldn't he escape special characters if he has the string?

Comment: @Marcin: I think how this is done is the actual question here. The "I can't add '\' into it to ignore special character" is referring to the manual escaping, probably.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `re.escape`:

```
>>> p = 'foo+*bar'
>>> import re
>>> re.escape(p)
'foo\\+\\*bar'
```

Or just use string operations to check if `p` is inside another string:

```
>>> p in 'blablafoo+*bar123'
True
>>> 'foo+*bar foo+*bar'.count(p)
2
```

By the way, this is mainly useful if you want to embed `p` into a proper regex:

```
>>> re.match(r'\d.*{}.*\d'.format(re.escape(p)), '1 foo+*bar 2')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f11e83a31d0>
```

Comment: I want to use re.findall(), so I think re.escape() is best for me! :)

Comment: @ZhuShengqi: To search for a verbatim string, `re.findall()` is essentially useless; `res.findall("ab", "abcabcabc")` results in `["ab", "ab", "ab"]`.  You probably want `str.count()`.

Comment: @Zhu: Yep, if you don't *need* regular expressions, don't use them. Circumstances where the escaping might be useful are (a) You want to integrate `p` into a more complex regex (b) You want to match against a list of regular expressions of which some are just plain text searches and some are more complex.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a regex, and just want to test if the pattern is a substring of the string, use:

```
if pattern in string:
```

If you want to test at the start or end of the string:

```
if string.startswith(pattern): # or .endswith(pattern)
```

See the [string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) section of the docs for other string methods.

If you need to know all locations of a substring in a string, use [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
offsets = []
offset = string.find(pattern, 0)
while offset != -1:
    offsets.append(offset)
    # start from after the location of the previous match
    offset = string.find(pattern, offset + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` on strings. This returns the index of the first occurence of the "needle" string (or `-1` if it's not found). e.g.

```
>>> a = 'test string 1+2*3'
>>> a.find('str')
5
>>> a.find('not there')
-1
>>> a.find('1+2*')
12
```