# Difference of two character vectors with substring

Tags: r

I have two lists:

```
a <- c("da", "ba", "cs", "dd", "ek")
b <- c("zyc", "ulk", "mae", "csh", "ddi", "dada")
```

I want to remove the elements from list b which would have a substring match with any of the values in a, e.g.

```
grepl("da","dada") # TRUE
```

How would you go about doing this efficiently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can `paste` the 'a' elements to a single string with `|` as the delimiter, use that as `pattern` in `grepl`, negate (`!`) to subset 'b'.

```
 b[!grepl(paste(a, collapse="|"), b)]
```

Comment: I guess instead of !grepl one could also use the invert parameter. But: What if a containts regex characters, such as "."?

Comment: To answer my own question: I used http://stackoverflow.com/a/14838321/1563867 on the a-vector, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Comment: @oliver13 I guess you solved the problem.  If not, consider to provide some example and expected output.

Answer (score 5):

And another solution using a simple for loop:

```
sel <- rep(FALSE, length(b))
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  sel <- sel | grepl(a[i], b, fixed = TRUE)
}
b[!sel]
```

Not as elegant as some as the other solutions (especially the one by akrun), but showing that a for loop isn't always as slow in R as people believe:

```
fun1 <- function(a, b) {
  sel <- rep(FALSE, length(b))
  for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    sel <- sel | grepl(a[i], b, fixed = TRUE)
  }
  b[!sel]
}

fun2 <- function(a, b) {
  b[!apply(sapply(a, function(x) grepl(x,b, fixed=TRUE)),1,sum)]
}

fun3 <- function(a, b) {
  b[-which(sapply(a, grepl, b, fixed=TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
}

fun4 <- function(a, b) {
  b[!grepl(paste(a, collapse="|"), b)]
}

library(stringr)
fun5 <- function(a, b) {
  b[!sapply(b, function(u) any(str_detect(u,a)))]
}

a <- c("da", "ba", "cs", "dd", "ek")
b <- c("zyc", "ulk", "mae", "csh", "ddi", "dada")
b <- rep(b, length.out = 1E3)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(a, b), fun2(a, b), fun3(a,b), fun4(a,b), fun5(a,b))


# Unit: microseconds
#       expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq        max neval  cld
# fun1(a, b)   389.630   399.128   408.6146   406.007   411.7690    540.969   100 a   
# fun2(a, b)  5274.143  5445.038  6183.3945  5544.522  5762.1750  35830.143   100   c 
# fun3(a, b)  2568.734  2629.494  2691.8360  2686.552  2729.0840   2956.618   100  b  
# fun4(a, b)   482.585   511.917   530.0885   528.993   541.6685    779.679   100 a   
# fun5(a, b) 53846.970 54293.798 56337.6531 54861.585 55184.3100 132921.883   100    d
```

Comment: Yeah that microseconds benchmark is meaningless, you should create a bit bigger data set IMO

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
b[!(+(apply(sapply(a, function(x) grepl(x,b)),1,sum)) > 0)]
[1] "zyc" "ulk" "mae"
```

'Peeling' this previous call from the inside, the results are the following: First, obtain a matrix of matches from the `grepl:` call (with `sapply`):

```
sapply(a, function(x) grepl(x,b))
#        da    ba    cs    dd    ek
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Note that the columns are the elements of `a` and the rows are the elements of `b`.

Then, `apply` the function sum per rows (in `R`, TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0:

```
apply(sapply(a, function(x) grepl(x,b)),1,sum)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Note that here, the row sums might be > 1 (if there is more than 1 match), so it must be coerced into a logical with the previous call wrapped around:

```
+() > 0
```

With this, we can match (`[`) the indices of b, but since we want the *opposite*, we use the operator `!`.

```
#full code:
step.one <- sapply(a, function(x) grepl(x,b))
step.two <- apply(step.one,1,sum)
step.three <- +(step.two > 0)
step.four <- !step.three
#finally:
b[step.four]
```

As David shows in the comments, this is a much more elegant approach:

```
b[-which(sapply(a, grepl, b), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
```

Comment: If you want to use `sapply` here, `b[-which(sapply(a, grepl, b), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]` would be probably better than combining it with `apply`

Comment: Or `b[rowSums(sapply(a, grepl, x=b))==0]` or since you know the length of output, use the faster `vapply`: `b[rowSums(vapply(a, grepl, x=b, logical(length(b)) ))==0]`

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for - but clearly way more complicated than the grepl-way akrun suggested