# find json in string with R

Tags: r, json, regex

Given a string i want to extract jsons within that string.

Very similar to this Question: [Find JSON strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-)
string. Just for R.

Basically, i Need to take the regex and Escape characters if necessary. Therefore, i looked into: [Is there an R function to escape a string for regex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836754/is-there-an-r-function-to-escape-a-string-for-regex-characters).

What i tried:

```
txt <- "asdd {a:b, c:d} asdasd"
library(stringr)
quotemeta <- function(string) {
  str_replace_all(string, "(\\W)", "\\\\\\1")
}

quotemeta("\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}")
str_extract_all(string = txt, pattern = quotemeta("\\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\\}"))
str_extract_all(string = txt, pattern = "\\{\\(\\?\\:\\[\\^\\{\\}\\]\\|\\(\\?R\\)\\)\\*\\}")
str_extract_all(string = txt, pattern = "\\\\{\\(\\?\\:\\[\\^\\{\\}\\]\\|\\(\\?R\\)\\)\\*\\\\}")
```

Comment: ICU regex engine does not support recursion. Use `regmatches` / `gregexpr`  with a PCRE regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use  `regexpr()` and `regmatches()`.

- `regexpr(pattern,text)` : Take the position of text which match the pattern.
- `regmatches(m,x)` : Extract matched text.
- `pattern` : Turn `\{` `\}` into `\\{` `\\}`.

```
regexpr("\\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\\}",txt,perl = T) %>% regmatches(x=txt)
#[1] "{a:b, c:d}"
```

This pattern may be easier for understanding.

- This pattern is `\\{(\\S|\\s)+\\}` :

  - `\\{` means the curly bracket  "{"
  - `(\\S|\\s)+` means all whitespace characters and non-whitespace characters between curly brackets.
  - `\\}` means the curly bracket  "}"

```
regexpr("\\{(\\S|\\s)+\\}",txt,perl = T) %>% regmatches(x=txt)
#[1] "{a:b, c:d}"
```

Hope it is useful to you :)

Comment: great answer and welcome to #SO! Probably, more a note to myself and not asked in the spec,.....(but Maybe someone else Needs it: If there are multiple jsons just use `gregexpr()` instead of `regexpr()`.

Comment: I'm so happy to see your feedback. Thank you so much =)