# Extract array of objects from string in R

Tags: r, regex

Suppose i have the following string:

```
str <- "var x = 1; var b = [{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}]; var notOfInterest = {cc:r, dd:w}"
```

I would like to extract all objects within that array "[{...}, {...}]" not single objects "{...}" (in this example: var notOfInterest).

**Desired Output:**

```
> list(c("{a:c, d:f}", "{aa:cc, dd:ff}"))
[[1]]
[1] "{a:c, d:f}"     "{aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

**What i tried:**

Building on this Question/answer: [find json in string with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295921/find-json-in-string-with-r) i tried to add brackets. 
I tried with adjusted Input string:
  `str2 <- "var x = 1; var b = [{a:c, d:f}]; var notOfInterest = {cc:r, dd:w}"`
(just for Debugging purposes. str is still my target string). Even that step doesnt work. After that i would have to add an optional comma and allow the object to appear multiple times.

```
gregexpr(
  pattern = "[\\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*?\\}]",
  perl = TRUE,
  text = str
) %>%
  regmatches(x = str)
```

I tried with "fixed = TRUE" Parameter, escaping the brackets and some more options which i am very happy to post the code for, but
i guess the question will get too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using stringr package like that;

```
library(stringr)
str <- "var x = 1; var b = [{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}]; var notOfInterest = {cc:r, dd:w}"
```

To match first occurrence only and result will be vector

```
str_extract(str, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
# [1] "{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

To get all occurrences and result will be a list

```
str_extract_all(str, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
# [[1]]
# [1] "{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` with `grep`

```
strsplit(gsub(".*\\[|\\]", "", grep("\\},", strsplit(str, ";")[[1]], 
            value = TRUE)), ", (?=\\{)", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "{a:c, d:f}"     "{aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

---

Another option is `rm_square` from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_square(str, extract = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub` and `strsplit`.

```
strsplit(gsub("^.*?(\\{.*?\\}).*(\\{.*?\\}).*$", "\\1£\\2", str), "£")
# [[1]]
# [1] "{a:c, d:f}"     "{aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the other solutions.

- For your Debugging purposes

> note: use the "[" and "]" need escape to be just text because "[" and "]"are special regex characters in regular expression.

```
str2 <- "var x = 1; var b = [{a:c, d:f}]; var notOfInterest = {cc:r, dd:w}" 

str2 %>% regexpr(
  pattern = "\\[\\{((\\s|\\S)+)\\}\\]",
  perl = TRUE
) %>%
  regmatches(x = str2)
#[1] "[{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}]"
```

- For your main purpose

  Use `gsub` and `strsplit`

  - Extract the array text.

    `gsub(pattern = "^.+\\[(.+)\\].+$",perl = T, replacement = "\\1")`

    - `pattern = "^.+\\[(.+)\\].+$"` : use "(.+)"make texts between "[" and "]" as a string group . In this example , string group will be "{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}".
    - `replacement = "\\1"` : replace original text with a string group .
  - Extract objects in the array.

    `strsplit(split = "(?<=([\\{\\}]))\\,\\s", perl = T)`

    - `split = "(?<=([\\{\\}]))\\,\\s"` : split the array  by the ", " between "}" and "{".

```
str <- "var x = 1; var b = [{a:c, d:f}, {aa:cc, dd:ff}]; var notOfInterest = {cc:r, dd:w}"

str %>% gsub(pattern = "^.+\\[(.+)\\].+$",
             perl = T,
             replacement = "\\1") %>% strsplit(split = "(?<=([\\{\\}]))\\,\\s", perl = T)
# [[1]]
# [1] "{a:c, d:f}"     "{aa:cc, dd:ff}"
```

I hope it will help you :)